# How to change Font of Whole Website or the whole HTML?

Tags: html

I have WhatsCast.in And I want to change font of the whole Website or the HTML file.. Help.. I am new to coding so tell me where to put the code and so...
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: on the html tag, add a class. in your css file add a font-family to that class. all elements inside the html will change font unless it is overridden in a lower level

Comment: Since I only see this question of yours but you still seem to be question banned on Stack (continuing the conversation I tried to start in meta), you may want to read this question on meta to give you tips on getting unbanned :) http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp) a list of web safe fonts to choose from

HTML

```
<html class="myFontClass">

</html>
```

css

```
.myFontClass{
    font-family: Helvetica; 
}
```

Comment: What if I want to use other font?

Comment: besides the list I just gave you? look up the css for that font or look at the format in the link and try it out.... it's also important to have back-up fonts just in case the browser or device does not interpret the first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put the `font-family` declaration into a body selector:

```
body {
  font-family: Algerian;
}
```

All the elements on your page will inherit this font-family then (unless, of course you override it later).